# Sort the values in a histogram in python and plot them

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, histogram

So say I have the following:

[1,5,1,1,6,3,3,4,5,5,5,2,5]

Counts:
1-3
2-1
3-2
4-1
5-5
6-1

Now, I wanted to print a plot like a histogram that is sorted on the x axis, as in:

not : 1 2 3 4 5 6

But sorted by the total number: 2 4 6 3 1 5.

Please help me out! Thanks...

My current plotting code is:

```
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    plt.xlim(0,1)
    plt.axvline(x=.85, color='r',linewidth=0.1)
    plt.hist(correlation,2000,(0.0,1.0))
    plt.xlabel(index[thecolumn]+' histogram')
    plt.ylabel('X Data')

    savefig(histogramsave,format='pdf')
```

Comment: How did you try to accomplish this, and where did it go wrong? Post your current code and people will be able to help - as it is, we would have to write the whole thing.

Comment: plt.clf()
  plt.cla()
  plt.xlim(0,1)
  plt.axvline(x=.85, color='r',linewidth=0.1)
  plt.hist(correlation,2000,(0.0,1.0))
  plt.xlabel(index[thecolumn]+' histogram')
  plt.ylabel('Value')
  
  savefig(histogramsave,format='pdf')

Comment: It's best to edit that into your question so it's readable.

Comment: Oh I am so sorry! My apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`, sort the items with `sorted`, passing in a custom key function:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> values = [1,5,1,1,6,3,3,4,5,5,5,2,5]
>>> counts = Counter(values)
>>> for k, count in reversed(counts.most_common()):
>>>     print(k, count * 'x')

2 x
4 x
6 x
3 xx
1 xxx
5 xxxxx
```

Comment: Hey, the thing is, I need to plot a histogram in the same way you are printing it. Any clue how I can do that?

Comment: @gran_profaci In the above code you can take both the keys and the values (k, v) as numpy arrays and do a scatter plot using matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(k, v)

Answer (score 1):

Steven has the right idea. The collections library can do your lifting.

If you otherwise want to do the work by hand, you could build something like this:

```
data = [1,5,1,1,6,3,3,4,5,5,5,2,5]
counts = {}
for x in data:
    if x not in counts.keys():
        counts[x]=0
    counts[x]+=1

tupleList = []
for k,v in counts.items():
    tupleList.append((k,v))

for x in sorted(tupleList, key=lambda tup: tup[1]):
    print "%s" % x[0],
print
```

Answer (score 0):

You must count and sort it, as in example below:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = [1,5,1,1,6,3,3,4,5,5,5,2,5]
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for e in l:
...     d[e] += 1
... 
>>> print sorted(d,key=lambda e:d[e])
[2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 5]
```